# How to write Django model to get record from multiple tables?

Tags: python, mysql, django, join, django-models

```
class Game(models.Model):
    total_players = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Players(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='players')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Player Name")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Score(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Players, related_name='scores')
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How do I write this query with Django models?

```
select p.name, sum(s.score) as total_score
from game g, players p, score s
where g.id=17 and  g.id = p.game_id and p.id = s.name_id
group by p.name
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this, but I'm not sure offhand if it will appropriately filter the scores to those for each player. I don't think your relationships are fully normalized - if `Score` is many-to-one for `Players`, and `Players` is many-to-one with `Game`, you wouldn't normally track `game` as an independent FK on `Score`. Can each `Players` row really exist only for a single game?

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Game.objects.filter(id=17).values(players__name).annotate(total_score=Sum(players__scores_score))
```

Comment: Yeah, I know relationship is not fully normalized. For this db structure each players exists only for single game I am learning django models joining and stuff so I started as 1NF/2NF. https://github.com/patelanuj28/black3_score_board

Comment: Did the query at least work for you? Normalization is usually a good idea but it's not strictly necessary as long as you think about the possible ambiguities that could be introduced without it.